# jQuery to replace characters in string for multiple instances of a class

Tags: jquery, css, string, replace

I have a css class called product-attributes which is used several times on one page, each class containing a different string. All of these strings contain commars which I would simply like to replace with br tags. I came up with the below code, but this replaces all the strings with the exact same string (from correcting the first class instance).

```
$('.product-attributes').html($('.product-attributes').html().replace(/,/g,'<br />'));
```

Where am I going wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Calling `html()` with selector will be called for only `first` element being returned by the selector. You need to use `each()` to replace the string in all occurrences.

```
$('.product-attributes').each(function(){    
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/,/g,'<br />'));    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to call the function on every instance of the class. Otherwise you will just be changing the html of every element with that class to the html of the first instance of the class. As you described above.

```
$('.product-attributes').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/,/g,'<br />'));
});
```